# Upload data to GAE using Excel VBA Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, google-app-engine, excel

I would like to create a spreadsheet that allows my users to do bulk uploads to my App Engine application and I would like to do so whilst exposing as little of my app to the world as possible.

My constraints are that I would like this to work via a button in Excel that turns the data in to http post requests, I like this as a plan as it means I can write the logic for one row and then the http response can validate to the user if the data has been accepted or generated an error.

I think I see two options;

1. Use a secured handler that forces the user to be logged in with their Google account - but this means figuring out how to implement communicating the authentication to Google. This also means my VBA code handling the user's password which I am nervous about.
2. Use a secret, this can be generated by the application so that only a user can access the code for which they have to be logged in to find.

Questions:

- Which approach should I take with my application?
- Is Option 2 materially less secure?
- What can I do to make option 2 a better solution?
- Should I even bother attempting option 1?

Comment: for (2), shouldn't it be the way round and use `HttpWebRequest` and get a token from your app?

Comment: What would stop somebody else using the same URL to get themselves a valid token?

Comment: oauth2? or you do not prefer to asking user to input login credentials?

Comment: I would be ok with asking users to input their credentials if I could find a good guide on how to do so. (For VBA)

Comment: take a look of [this](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/guests/oauth2), this could be just what you want. However the `token` is stored in plain text in registry, you may want to override this and store only hashed token. Good luck!